# Parsing specific numeric data from csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

Good morning.

I have series of data in cvs file like below,

1,,,

1,137.1,1198,1.6

2,159,300,0.4

3,176,253,0.3

4,197,231,0.3

5,198,525,0.7

6,199,326,0.4

7,215,183,0.2

8,217.1,178,0.2

9,244.2,416,0.5

10,245.1,316,0.4

I want to extract specific data from second column for example 217.1 and 245.1 and have them concatenated into a new file like,

8,217.1,178,0.2

10,245.1,316,0.4

I use cvs module to read my cvs file, but, I can't extract specific data as I desire. Could anyone kindly please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
results = []
reader = csv.reader(open('file.csv'))
for line in reader:  # iterate over the lines in the csv
    if line[1] in ['217.1','245.1']:  # check if the 2nd element is one you're looking for
        results.append(line)    # if so, add this line the the results list
```

or if you want to convert to numbers, replace the last line with

```
        results.append([float(x) for x in line])  # append a list of floats instead of strings
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Misunderstood what the question was about, sorry.

I'm not sure where the problem is, You mean row not column?

As you can see in the [docs for `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

You can easily access each row:

```
>>> import csv  
>>> spamReader = csv.reader(open('eggs.csv'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')  
>>> for row in spamReader:  
...     print ', '.join(row)  
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans  
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

And (ok my python days are some years old) for the columns you could e.g just do

```
result += row[0] + "," + row[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
import csv
r = csv.reader(file(r'orig.csv'))
w = csv.writer(file(r'new.csv', 'w'))
for line in r:
    if line[0] in ['8','10']: # look for the data in lines 8 and 10
        w.writerow(line)
```